# increasing i in a loop in python

Tags: python, loops, printing, digraphs

Can I somehow create a loop that runs through some code I have and for every time it runs through the loop `a` increases, and print out the line in the bottom?

```
a=0

str1 = h[a]


dG = nx.DiGraph()

for i, word in enumerate(str1):

    try:
        next_word = str1[i + 1]
        if not dG.has_node(word):
            dG.add_node(word)
            dG.node[word]['count'] = 1
        else:
            dG.node[word]['count'] += 1
        if not dG.has_node(next_word):
            dG.add_node(next_word)
            dG.node[next_word]['count'] = 0

        if not dG.has_edge(word, next_word):
            dG.add_edge(word, next_word, weight=maxint - 1)
        else:
            dG.edge[word][next_word]['weight'] -= 1
    except IndexError:
        if not dG.has_node(word):
            dG.add_node(word)
            dG.node[word]['count'] = 1
        else:
            dG.node[word]['count'] += 1
    except:
        raise

for node in dG.nodes():
print '%s:%d\n' % (node, dG.node[node]['count'])
```

**update**

`ha[a]` in `str1=h[a`] contains a bunch of list like this:

```
['14th_century', 'Time', 'Isaac_Newton', 'Rainbow']
['14th_century', 'Time', 'Light', 'Rainbow']
['14th_century', 'Time', 'Light', 'Color', 'Rainbow']
```

I was thinking if I could run a loop that increases `a` in `str1 = h[a]`, I could get this output:

```
Rainbow:2

Color:1

Isaac_Newton:1

Time:3

Light:2

14th_century:3
```

But right now it only counts for that one line I have chosen `a` to be? Does this make any sense?

Comment: I don't know what `a` stands for. Can you be more specific about your intended output?

Comment: So you just want to increment `a`? Do you want to print `a` each iteration or only once?

Comment: isn't this what `i` already does?

Comment: i have given you some more info above in the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def printStuff(labels,dG):
    for index, node in enumerate(dG.nodes()):
        print '%s:%d\n' % (labels[index],dG.node[node]['count'])   


dG = nx.DiGraph()

for i, word in enumerate(str1):

    try:
        next_word = str1[i + 1]
        if not dG.has_node(word):
            dG.add_node(word)
            dG.node[word]['count'] = 1
        else:
            dG.node[word]['count'] += 1
        if not dG.has_node(next_word):
            dG.add_node(next_word)
            dG.node[next_word]['count'] = 0

        if not dG.has_edge(word, next_word):
            dG.add_edge(word, next_word, weight=maxint - 1)
        else:
            dG.edge[word][next_word]['weight'] -= 1
    except IndexError:
        if not dG.has_node(word):
            dG.add_node(word)
            dG.node[word]['count'] = 1
        else:
            dG.node[word]['count'] += 1
    except:
        raise

    printStuff(h[i], dG)
```

Comment: I get a list Index out of range ?